# Ошибка при запуске бота в Telegram

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

Я новичок самоучка, пытаюсь создать своего первого бота и усовершенствовать в образовательных целях.
Бота зарегистрировал, добавил команды и т.п.
Пишу код, который описан на многих сайта (см. код в IDLE)

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot('919пппппппппппппAN3oGg')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, ты написал мне /start')

bot.polling()
```

При разных вариация получаю простыню ошибок:

> 2019-11-12 15:48:05,490 (util.py:65 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot:
>   "ConnectionError occurred, args=(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.',
>   ConnectionRefusedError(61, 'Connection refused')),) Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 542, in urlopen

Я что-то пишу не так или нужен прокси?

Comment: ConnectionRefused

Comment: Да, определено нужен прокси...